# How do you keep the client_secret value in the repository when you implement the OAuth2.0 Server?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am implementing OAuth2.0 Server. At first I converted client_secret to Bcrypt and saved it.
So we could not query client_secret again.

I need to query the third party vendor to provide a client_secret value.
How do you encrypt the client_secret value and store it in the repository?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is hard to understand. Can you specify what you mean by "situations where client secret should be queried" and what to explain more in detail what you are concerned about?

Comment: Clientsecrets should be known to third party developers. Usually the developer center will deliver it. At that point you need a lookup. How do you store clientsecret?